# Magento2 Database Basic PDO Details

Tags: database, magento2, php-pdo

Regarding the upcoming Magento version 2 I'm asking myself, if:

- Will it make use of PDO?
- And if so, will it make use of PDO emulated prepares<sup>[1]</sup> ?

I'm also asking myself about similar PDO related issues, like the usage of "`SET NAMES`" in Magento 1. Will this be part of the DSN or has the old database/configuration layer that interfaces with PDO taken in 1:1 from Magento 1?

<sup>[1]</sup> `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`; http://php.net/pdo.setattribute

Answer (score 1):

***Note:*** As Magento 2 isn't released yet, the questions can only be answered to the time of date from sources publicly available.

> Will it make use of PDO?

Yes it will make use of PDO. It's the only DB interface offered so far:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/Resource/Type/Db

> Will it make use of PDO emulated prepares?

Yes, emulated prepares are explicitly enabled by default:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L335

---

Despite there are many new classes all around and Magento as usual is a database centric application, the underlying code is pretty much copied over from Magento 1 with no or only decorative changes. This includes [keeping the Mysql 4 compatbile SQL mode](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L332) (the comment given suggests that this is wanted), keeping the [*known Problems with setting the character set with SQL* (see Example #1)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) or keeping the complicated way to configure the database adapter (e.g. you still can't use DSN nor aliasing which is a feature of PDO). The love for the past is still heated, underlying of all this you find [`\Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.html).